# Pass this.method to super call JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

So, I have a base class that accepts functions in the constructor. In the derived class, I am trying to pass references to child methods to the super call.

Code is something like this:

```js
class Base {
    constructor(...fns) {
        //Store fns for later call
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    fn1 = () => {}
    fn1 = () => {}
    constructor() {
        super(
            this.fn1,
            this.fn2
        )
    }
}
```

But I get the error "must call super constructor before accessing 'this'".
I know why this is happening, and I have an idea of how to fix it (wrapping `this.fn1` like `() => this.fn1()`), but... I like conciseness.
Is there a way I can get away with passing references to a childs methods into a super call?

Comment: Based on the code you showed, the `derived` class has no relationship to the `base` class.

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super#description) addresses your issue.

Comment: Yes, I see I forgot to extend `Base` in my example. Fixed, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Before the object is instantiated by the `super()` call, the methods do not exist and cannot be accessed. But you don't need to use methods anyway, just pass some functions:

```
class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super(
            () => {},
            () => {},
        );
    }
}
```

Alternatively, [don't use class fields](https://www.charpeni.com/blog/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think) but proper method definitions, and refer to the methods via the prototype object:

```
class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super(
            Derived.prototyp.fn1,
            Derived.prototyp.fn2,
        );
    }
    fn1() {}
    fn2() {}
}
```

Comment: How does using the prototype version work? Would the functions still be able to access instance data? The methods I'm passing require access to the data stored in the class

Comment: Also, the data they are accessing are marked as private `#data`, does that affect things?

Comment: You haven't really shown what the `Base` constructor does with those functions. Assuming it calls them later, when the instance is actually created, *on* that instance (e.g. `fn.call(this)`), yes the methods will be able to access that instance. Same for the arrow functions. And both can access private fields, if the name (`#data`) is in scope and the field has already been created.